# How to get CSS selector for the clear input field?

Tags: html, css, selenium, css-selectors, automated-tests

How to get a CSS selector of an "X" element used for clearing the text inside of an input field:

[image]

The HTML is here:

```
<div class="input-group search-in-card border-bottom-0 border-right">
  <input class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" type="search" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text">
      <fa-icon class="ng-fa-icon" icon="search">
        <svg role="img" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="search" class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
      </fa-icon>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Selenium to click it but can't seem to find it in HTML. When there is no text entered in the field, frontend looks like this, but with no visible change in HTML:

[image]

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: No, it is for business purposes.

Comment: Is it a browser specific clear icon ? Because, I couldn't find the related html in the code. Can you check in other browsers?

Comment: OK, I understand. I'm quite sure the elements are appearing and disappearing on the page accordingly to the state of other elements. So that X element appears when the search field is non-empty. I faced this many time.

Comment: @AbinThaha You are up to something. :) It is present in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @Prophet That's correct. X appears when the search field is non-empty. How can you solve that?

Comment: So you expect the X to be eliminated completely ?

Comment: @AbinThaha I need to get some way of knowing if the x is present or not. Weather to wait for it to appear or to click it (depending on the test case). I need that for test automation.

Comment: @MateMrše You can see it in dev tool. I'm 100% sure. I would do it if I could, but you don't share the link....

Comment: As @Prophet mentioned, you might be able to find it in the dev tools, may be as a pseudo class.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type = 'search']::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
    color: green;
    background-color: red;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;   
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
/*  position: absolute;
    right: 0; */
    border-radius: 50%;

}



.input::-webkit-search-cancel-button:after{
    content: "✖️";
    color: green;
/*  outline: 1px solid red; */
/*  border: 1px solid red; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    tranform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This is how it can be styled in css. `::-webkit-search-cancel-button` is whats holding the value. But I am not sure how can it be selected using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove text from the search bar, you can do it not only by clicking on X. The following way selects all the text entered in Search field and removes it by hitting Delete btn on a keyboard:

```
driver.findElement("your search bar selector here").sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a" + Keys.DELETE));
```

Or by clicking on X directly:

I suspect this is a selector for your X element:

```
"span[class='input-group-text'] [icon='search']"
```

So try this one:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='input-group-text'] [icon='search']")).click();
```

**UPDATE:**

To assert visibility/invisibility of X, do following:

```
WebElement xButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='input-group-text'] [icon='search']"));
    
    AssertTrue(xButton.isDisplayed());
    // Or
    AssertFalse(xButton.isDisplayed());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know to delete text, I just want to be able to assert visibility/invisibility of the x.

Comment: @MateMrše okay, I've updated my answer on how to assert it. Check it out.